# When can you avoid libel by preceding a false statement with "Sources say" or "I heard"?

Tags: united-states, civil-law, libel

Suppose the New York Times writes "Sources say the celebrity John Doe raped his daughter"
and they truly found two anonymous people (i.e., two sources) beforehand with that claim.

How responsible is the company in civil court if the claim is false?

Of course, the company will lose readers as its reputation for finding good
sources falls, but I'm wondering how egregious of a statement would be permitted
before New York civil law would punish it further.

I assume the company would have civil liability if they knew the claim was false and simply had knowingly found two liars, right?

But, if the company had the tiniest suspicion of truth, are they instead protected from libel?  It seems the news is quite free to propagate rumors, so
I'd like to know the limit.  Are there precedents of libel like this where the
publisher never actually lied?

Comment: Also see https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/21826

Comment: I wouldn't assume that a company will lose readership as its reputation falls. Look at TMZ.

Answer (score 2):

For a public figure in [united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states), the standard is [actual malice](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actual_malice): “that is, with knowledge that it was false or with reckless disregard of whether it was false or not.” *New York Times Co. v. Sullivan*, 376 U.S. 254 (1964)

A newspaper can be negligent in checking its information, but it can’t be reckless. It would be reckless for a newspaper to publish a claim that I made about person X without them verifying that I actually know person X, could have actual knowledge of the claim and could provide reasonable support for my claim  *if* they are going to attribute me as a “source” because the word implies that I know what I’m talking about. If they are going to use my name, then they are not providing any truth weight of their own.

Comment: In my specific example to make sure I understand, the company could lose a libel suit if it had also interviewed the daughter who vehemently denied the claim, but then had left this denial out of the publication, right?  Do you also have any actual precedent examples where a company was found guilty of libel?  I'm not aware of guilty precedents, but they would help to understand the somewhat arbitrary threshold for "recklessness" towards a public figure.

Comment: By the way, a Twitter precedent would be interesting, but it is probably too early to ask for them.  This article from late 2017 makes me suspect that no guilty verdicts (ignoring out-of-court settlements) have ever come in favor of a public figure over a tweet: https://www.minclaw.com/how-to-report-slander-on-twitter

Comment: @bobuhito Anyway, the claim that "sources say the celebrity John Doe raped his daughter" is not false.

Comment: Claim = "the celebrity John Doe raped his daughter" = FALSE (I still think this is all clear in my question)

Comment: @bobuhito actually the claim is that " sources say ...."   OTOH, if the NYT had no source (even if anon ) that would be malice

Comment: @bobuhito there are two claims.  Some source has (or sources have) claimed that John Doe raped his daughter.  The newspaper, however, has only reported the fact that sources have made that claim, which is true, even if the claim itself is false.

Comment: I understood from the beginning that you can always make a higher-level claim from any claim.  In my question, the claim was false, the higher-level claim was true, which was exactly why I asked and still can't answer:  Has a company ever been found guilty of libel towards a public figure in this case?

Comment: "In January, malicious rumours appeared on twitter that <celebrity> had supposedly raped his daughter", would that be safe to report?